# How to enable paging in x86 and display GDT in UEFI

Tags: x86, paging, uefi, gdt

My goal is to enable paging in x86 in UEFI. My professor said, that I may first try to display GDT in UEFI - that way I will also see if paging works. 
The problem is, that I have no idea how to do it.

I used this tutorial to enable EDK2 in Visual Studio: http://uefi.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-set-up-edk2s-windows-hosted-uefi.html

Can you point me to any tutorial or explain what should I do?

Comment: I presume you mean "enable paging mode" as opposed to "page bits of memory in and out", since the specification requires a 1:1 mapping of all RAM? I also presume you are explicitly planning this for IA32, since X64 is required to always run with paging mode enabled?

Comment: Yes, I plan this for IA32 and want to enable paging mode

Comment: Well, you could look at doing the opposite of what happens in IntelFspWrapperPkg/Library/BaseFspApiLib/X64/Thunk64To32.S when the X64 port prepares to run IA32 code.